# How to Understand Code on zyBooks Ch. 4 Program: Drawing a half arrow

Tags: c

This program outputs a downwards facing arrow composed of a rectangle and a right triangle. The arrow dimensions are defined by user specified arrow base height, arrow base width, and arrow head width.

(1) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of height arrowBaseHeight. (1 pt)

(2) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow base of width arrowBaseWidth. Use a nested loop in which the inner loop draws the *’s, and the outer loop iterates a number of times equal to the height of the arrow base. (1 pt)

(3) Modify the given program to use a loop to output an arrow head of width arrowHeadWidth. Use a nested loop in which the inner loop draws the *’s, and the outer loop iterates a number of times equal to the height of the arrow head. (2 pts)

(4) Modify the given program to only accept an arrow head width that is larger than the arrow base width. Use a loop to continue prompting the user for an arrow head width until the value is larger than the arrow base width. (1 pt)

These are what it is wanting to me to do i just dont understand here is the code it starts with

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arrowBaseHeight;
    int arrowBaseWidth;
    int arrowHeadWidth;

    printf("Enter arrow base height:\n");
    scanf("%d", &arrowBaseHeight);

    printf("Enter arrow base width:\n");
    scanf("%d", &arrowBaseWidth);

    printf("Enter arrow head width:\n");
    scanf("%d", &arrowHeadWidth);
    printf("\n");

    // Draw arrow base (height = 3, width = 2)
    printf( "**\n");
    printf( "**\n");
    printf( "**\n");

    // Draw arrow head (width = 4)
    printf( "****\n");
    printf( "***\n");
    printf( "**\n");
    printf( "*\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[What Zybooks wants it too look like minus the blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmVL2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We want to help you, but it makes no sense for us to just do an assignment for you.  You won't learn nearly as much as when you try it on your own.  So, try using either a **for** loop or a **while** loop to do the first piece and tell us what problems you encounter.

Comment: The biggest thing is i dont even know know how to start it at all

Comment: Sure, we all have to start somewhere ... When I search (using duckduckgo)  'tutorial while loop in C language' the top hit is here:   
 https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_while_loop.htm  Use that information and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ('Enter arrow base height:')
arrow_base_height = int(input())

print ('Enter arrow base width:')
arrow_base_width = int(input())

print ('Enter arrow head width:')
arrow_head_width = int(input())


while arrow_head_width <= arrow_base_width:
    print ('Enter arrow head width:')
    arrow_head_width = int(input())
print('')

for base_height in range(arrow_base_height):
  for base_width in range(arrow_base_width):
    print('*', end='')
  print('')

for head_width in range(arrow_head_width):
  for head in range(arrow_head_width - head_width):
    print('*', end='')
  print('')
```